# How to get a file that's one folder above Document Root?

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have edited Apache so that my document root is here:

```
/var/www/html/Code/web/
```

But now I want to point to a file that is inside the `~/Code/` folder.

Normally I could use:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Controllers/MyFile.php');
```

But that won't work with this new document root. So, without changing my document root, how can I point back to a folder that is in this path:

```
/var/www/html/Code/Controller/
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `../` to up one directory.

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../Controllers/MyFile.php');
```

Comment: I want to kiss you man  ... worked like a charm 

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar challenge to set the path to save files and the above solution didn't work unfortunately.

I ended up using this which works fine. "dirname" returns the folder "document_root" resides in - which is one level up.

```
$systemPath = dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/Controllers/MyFile.php';
```

Comment: Definitely better option, than raw playing with `../dot../..snakes/..` ;) also it's worthy to mention, that `dirname` function has `levels` parameter so you can traverse even higher in the structure if required.